# Tkinter exe file - DOS screen flashes but GUI does not persist

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, exe

I have created a GUI on Python 2.7.11 that consists of a main page along with page 1 and page 2 that are linked through buttons on main page. Converted main page to a python exe file using PyInstaller and there were no errors in the conversion. main page.exe appeared in the dist folder but on clicking it, a DOS screen flashed and the main page did not open nor persist on the screen. 
Being a beginner, I am not sure about how to proceed further. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a line like `root.mainloop()` at the end (with `root` standing for your main Tk window) to make sure the event loop runs, then you'll need to debug your code. Try running a small segment of the code at a time to see if all goes well, and see where it is that all doesn't go well; then examine the offending part closely to find the error, maybe running some lines of code in the interpreter from the command line to see what (if any) error messages you get.

On the other hand, if you *don't* have a line like `root.mainloop()` at the end, that could produce the error you saw. Being a Python beginner myself, and having learned to program in Tcl where the Tk event loop runs automatically, I've seen that error a few times myself. :o(

Comment: Thank you. Yes, my code does have root.mainloop() so the issue is with the fact that there are buttons which link the main page GUI and page 1/2 GUI. Will update once it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple issues associated with converting the Python Script that links modules through button clicks. Keeping in mind these factors, it would be best to convert it to exe using Cx_Freeze. It is more user-friendly and was highly effective for the GUI when compared to PyInstaller and Py2Exe.